# Show up Recently added places into AutocompleteTextView

Tags: google-places-api

I have implemented an Add Place option into  my app if the user find that the place isn't available in the AutocompleteTextView Google API,but after adding a place the place do not show up in the AutocompleteTextView option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).